# Catalook Remote API

Tags: web-services, dotnetnuke

I am trying to pull orders from Catalook using the remote API. Here is my code:

```
    CATALooKRemote.RemoteController remote = new CATALooKRemote.RemoteController();
    remote.Url = "http://localhost/Customers/DotNetNuke_Community_06.02.04_Install/DesktopModules/CATALooKStore/remote.asmx";
    bool log = remote.Login(0, "host", "dnnhost");
    Response.Write(log);
    var orders = remote.GetOrders(new DateTime(2009, 1, 1), new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), -1);
    foreach (var a in orders)
    {

    }

    //throws null reference exception
    Response.Write(orders.Count());
```

I have only one order in the system, but I cannot query it using this method. The order has paid status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the CATALookRemote service but looking at the WSDL, don't you need to pass the username, password and portal id as well?

```
SRVRemote.RemoteControllerSoapClient remote = new SRVRemote.RemoteControllerSoapClient();
List<SRVRemote.OrderDetailsRemote> oOrders = null;
oOrders = remote.GetOrders(System.DateTime.FromOADate(0), System.DateTime.Today, -1, 0, "MyUsername", "MyPassword");
foreach (SRVRemote.OrderDetailsRemote order in oOrders) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: For GetOrders, you must add a user name and password. For GetInvoices, you do not need a user name and password.